# Orphaned entries in aspnetdb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

After calling method

```
_membershipProvider.DeleteUser(user.UserName, false);
```

where where the second parameter (false) is deleteAllRelatedData, orphaned entries are left in the database (aspnet_Users table and probably more). What is the best practice for cleaning these up?

EDIT: The user management code is already changed to now use `true` as the second param, but it's left a db full of junk entries. I'm wondering how best to clean these up. I'm currently looking at the sp provided with the database `dbo.aspnet_Users_DeleteUser` puzzling over the parameter `@TablesToDeleteFrom int` wondering exactly what it means. Looks like some sort of bitmask.

Comment: Can you change the call to DeleteUser( ..., true ) ?

Comment: Nice one Bob- you should put this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer, Bob :) However, having run with the false parameter for a while, we've got a aspnetdb full'o'junk. That's what this question is about.

Comment: @RichardOD - I was going back and forth on that one. There were two strikes against it as an answer: first, it's as much a question as an answer. Second, I'm implying that @spender could qualify his original question, thereby making my answer irrelevant to his need.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'd have a choice of [Cascade delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28SQL.80%29.aspx) or write something that runs as a job periodically.

Or better yet do as stated in Bob's comment!

Update- as it sounds like you have now stopped this from occuring, just write a SQL Script to detect the orphaned records, then turn it into a DELETE statement.

Comment: I've added to my question... there are so many FK constraints in place that doing this turns out to be quite an arduous task. I'm looking at the supplied SP aspnet_Users_DeleteUser, which seems to have most of this "detection" already in place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave no orphan entries then you should set the second parameter (deleteAllRelatedData) to true. It will remove all related and child data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.deleteuser.aspx

Comment: Sadly the junk is already there. Looking for a nifty way to delete it all.